# Установка операционной системы на ноут eMashines e644

Tags: установка, windows, linux

Вопрос в следующем: как установить windows, когда на ноуте уже стоит linux и он не запускается?

Купил ноут, хотел поставить винду. В биосе выбрал приоритет cd/dvd, запустил и в тот момент, когда надо жать любую кнопку для запуска загрузки с диска всё останавливается. То есть появляется надпись starting CD..._ и на этом всё! Дальше ничего не происходит. Как мне быть? Помогите...

Comment: @moreman Этот вопрос правильно задать на [БитКоде][1].

[1]: http://user.hashcode.ru

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте диск с данными.
2. Проверьте режим совместимости винчестера в BIOS.
3. Загрузитесь с диска.
4. Там всё просто. ;)